# SQL table relationship not showing up in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ssms

Hey, I made several tables and relationships using SQL server manager. I then imported them to visual studio and it all appeared in the correct form, except one of the relationships did not appear. I have checked everything I could think of and it is the exact same as the other relationships. If you know anything I can check, I would appreciate it. Thanks

I am using the entity framework, visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by simply deleting the table and recreating. Finding the issue was not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the foreign-key relationships defined correctly? Do the tables in question have primary keys assigned?

Comment: Yes, both tables have primary keys assigned. I believe they are defined correctly. I made them in the sql server management studio